# hereNow() with state=true is not working

Tags: java, android, pubnub

I started working with PubNub for an Android app. But there is one issue I struggle with - I would like to retrieve the `state` information out of the `hereNow()` function. Given the API reference this should be possible with the Constructor

```
hereNow(java.lang.String channel, boolean state, boolean uuids, Callback callback)
```

<sub>([see the javadoc here](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/javadocs/com/pubnub/api/Pubnub.html#hereNow(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20com.pubnub.api.Callback)))</sub>

But it seems to me that this is just not working, as my app crashes when I use this constructor but works just fine when using

```
hereNow(java.lang.String channel, Callback callback)
```

The callback is very simple for testing:

```
Callback hereNowCallBack = new Callback(){
    @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        Log.d("PUBNUB","here now: " + message.toString());  
    }
};
```

I use the JAR version 3.6.3 if that matters.

This feature would be of incredible value to me as I would not need to get the state for each UUID after I found out which UUIDs are active in the channel.

By the way - what is the maximum size such a "state" can have?

Comment: Thank you for the report of the issue I've also sent an email to the team about your findings.

Comment: Can you share the crash log and code snippet when you use hereNow(java.lang.String channel, boolean state, boolean uuids, Callback callback) ?

Comment: @Devendream I will do that this evening after work. I call here now, subscribe, publish and presence out of a background service and all except for herenow with the state enabled work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.7 is newly released and available [here](https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/android).

If you are still experiencing issues with this even on 3.7, please contact us at support@pubnub.com.

Comment: Thanks jeremy, I didn't know about the new version, I will put it in place this evening and give feedback.

Comment: Made a first quick try and it seems to work with 3.7 :-)

Comment: Great! If you experience further issues, ping us at support@pubnub.com!